# Example of using find command with -ok NOT -exec

Tags: command-line, find

Can someone show me how to replace `-exec` with `-ok` in the command below?

```
find -name "*.swp" -exec rm {} "\;"
```

I'm told, and it says it on the "man page", that you can use `-ok` to "confirm".

I replaced `-exec` with `-ok` but I got an error:

```
find: missing argument to 'ok'
```

This is on ParrotOS.

Comment: Which platform is this on? The command find -name "*.swp" -ok rm {} ";" ran without errors for me on Manjaro

Comment: Thanks - I'm using parrot os

Comment: @GraceThompson the OP was using `"\;"` but the site ate the `\ ` since it wasn't in a code block.

Answer (score 5):

The command you show would give the exact same error. You need to end an `-exec` or `-ok` with a `;`. The `;` has a special meaning in the shell (e.g. `bash`) which is why this needs to be escaped, *either* as `";"` *or* as `\;`, but not both (`"\;"`), as you had in your question.

So try this:

```
find -name "*.swp" -ok rm {} \;
```

This will ask for confirmation before deleting each file. You can also get the same behavior, since you're on Linux, with `rm -i`:

```
find -name "*.swp" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks, yes it works with just \; - Unfortunately in my LFS101x Introduction to Linux course - they appear to have got it wrong by telling me I can use either ';' or "\;"!